# How can I create an index on the substring of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, indexing

I have a table containing key-value pairs which I would like to be ale to search efficiently on:

```
SELECT * WHERE meta_key = "User ID" AND meta_value = "123userId";
```

However due to a legacy requirement the key and value NVARCHAR storage might be as large as 255 and 1000 characters respectively. Indexing on such large columns is not only costly but also outright restricted on some db types.

I believe MySQL has a system to allow indexes by a `LEFT`-style substring as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_metadata_indexing_key_value ON metadata_indexing(meta_key, meta_value(255));
```

...however our system must support all three of MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle. Is this the right way to go about this, and if so, how do I make similar indexes on MSSQL and Oracle?

Comment: If you need a solution here, you're going to likely need different solutions for each vendor. All 3 use very different dialects. For SQL Server, I'd suggest adding a `PERSISTED` computed column and index that; then you can query that in the `WHERE` instead. Though, considering that you only want the `LEFT` side, a `LIKE` is likely sargable too `WHERE YourColumn LIKE '123userid%';` would use an index on your column `YourColumn`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's nothing in the ANSI SQL standard about indexing at all. Every vendor invents their own proprietary syntax and features for indexing. You need to be thinking about the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), because there is no syntax that will work in all vendors' implementations.

Comment: This sounds like both premature optimization and a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you find such a limited index useful?

Comment: "sounds like an x-y problem".  Also sounds like an EAV design, one of the worst concepts ever foisted on the RDBMS world.

Comment: As others have said, a database-agnostic solution does not exist.  For Oracle I'd look at function-based indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larnu suggested we ended up with a new computed `meta_value_short` column which needed to be produced separately for each db type. When querying...

**If the length is 255 or less:** Simply compare to `meta_value_short`.

**Otherwise:** first compare `LEFT(value, 255)` to `meta_value_short`, then additionally compare with `meta_value`.

---

For reference the computed column definitions are below:

**MSSQL:**
`ALTER TABLE [metadata_indexing] ADD meta_value_short AS (SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 255))`

**MySQL:**
`ALTER TABLE metadata_indexing ADD meta_value_short VARCHAR(255) AS (SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 255));`

**Oracle:**
`ALTER TABLE metadata_indexing ADD meta_value_short AS (SUBSTR(meta_value, 1, 255));`

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about WordPress, that index is only part of the solution.  When reaching into `postmeta`, you need a *composite* key *starting with* `post_id`.  More recommendations [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) .

Also, if the data is predictable enough, you might be able to replace the `LONGTEXT` will something more civilized, like `VARCHAR(150)`.  Do `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(meta_key)), MAX(LENGTH(meta_value)) FROM post_meta;`.

(I, too, pan EAV.  And especially WP's poor implementation.)

Comment: Nope, not a WordPress thing, entirely bespoke

Comment: @Arachin - Well, check my link to see if they messed up the indexes, too.