# How can I create an index on a substring of a text column?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-like, calculated-columns

I quite often need to filter records in a specific table on the basis of the existence of a substring in a text column. Specifically I need to exclude records that contain a `/`.

I currently use a `WHERE` statement such as:

```
WHERE table_name.text_col NOT LIKE "%/%"
```

My hunch is that searching the strings of every record for this substring takes a long time (relatively) and could be improved by indexing in some way. I could create a new binary indexed column and populate this based on whether the text column contains `/` but I was wondering if there is a neater solution for this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65112973/11277108) question which refers to a `LEFT()` style solution but I didn't understand the syntax and I'm looking for something that can cope with the substring being anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* create a computed column that persistently stores the information:

```
alter table table_name 
    add column text_has_slash tinyint
    generated always as (text_col like '%/%')
    stored
;
```

Or, if you want to treat `null` values as negatives:

```
    generated always as (coalesce(text_col like '%/%', 0))
```

The column value is computed *and stored* in the table (it is automatically updated by the database when the value changes).

Now you can use that column in your query:

```
select * from table_name where not text_has_slash;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5af2f7c7b3e2aef3d290c7cbbd0ca546)**

Filtering on a pre-computed value should already improve performance.

Creating an index on a boolean column does not necessarily help, because there are only three possible values (0, 1, null). Unless the values are very unevenly distributed, it is often faster for the database to perform a full scan. On the other hand, you might want to include this column in a multi-column index, if you have more search criteria than those you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is whether the entire table needs to be checked versus whether there is some way to limit the number of rows via an index.

First, let's decide whether such an index will even get used.  As a Rule of Thumb, if more than 20% of the table is matched by some index, that index won't be used.  (The "20" varies depending on the phase of the moon.)  The logic is that bouncing between the index's BTree and the data's BTree costs something.  Such bouncing is worth the effort if there aren't many rows -- that is when the index is "selective".

So, if more than 20% of the rows have "/", none of the suggestions will be efficient.  `LOCATE` may be more efficient than `LIKE`; a `REGEXP` is probably slower than either.  Still, the *main* cost in the query will be having to look at *every* row.

If, on the other hand, very few rows have "/", then any of the *pre-computed* indexes will be beneficial.

If the real test is `WHERE x LIKE '%/%' AND ...`, then we need to look at the secondary part of the test.  It *may* be that even a non-selective test for "/" can be effectively combined with the other part of the test.

Bottom line:  Give us the complete picture, plus some statistics.

Comment: I would place the usefulness of an index way below 20%, probably at 5%, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `LOCATE` can help you.

```
WHERE LOCATE('/', table_name.text_col) = 0
```

When `LOCATE` returns 0 it means that substring isn't find in string. More info at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate.

You asked for `LEFT()`, which isn't what you're looking for. This function returns substring from beginning of string. Syntax is simple, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Comment: This will also need to examine all records (a full table scan) to get the results.

Comment: Thanks. Will this be any faster than my current `WHERE` statement? Btw - I wasn't considering the `LEFT()` solution as I need something that "can cope with the substring being anywhere in the string."

Comment: @Luuk - thanks, you answered my question :) Do I have any indexing options here?

Comment: If you really need to query this, and you cannot change the data inside that column, then your own solution (creating a ' binary indexed column' ) should be the best.